# Managing entity changes in the current jhipster

Tags: hibernate, jpa, liquibase, jhipster

There seem to be efforts to bring better change management around entities in later version of jhipster, but what is the best practice in the current version? Is it through manual edits to entities and auto detection with hibernate config? or through liquidbase? Pls suggest. My app is going to have good amount of changes to entities and relationships as we move along with implementation.

https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/871

https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/754

Comment: I don't how I missed it. There is a high level approach mentioned at https://jhipster.github.io/development.html (look at database updates). Other useful link http://www.liquibase.org/bestpractices.html

Comment: Surprised to see -1. Information around entity change management in Jhipster is not clear, and it took time for me to figure out. I shared the above comment thinking it will help others.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace created entity by new one with the same name with next steps:

1.Rename your `.jhipster/EntityName.json` configuration file

2.Drop the table EntityName from your DB

3.Lunch command `yo jhipster:entity entityName`

4.Type `y` if the Jhipster asks you about overwriting the conflict files